# How to malloc matrix properly

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I am reading matrix from binary file. When I am printing my matrix, I get next output:

```
1 2 3 4 469762076
6 7 8 9 402653208
11 12 13 14 0
16 17 18 19 -1644166500
21 22 23 24 50397953
```

I don't know why I get these values at the end of each line. How can I solve this?

> This my code:

```
FILE *f = fopen("data_output.bin", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); 
int length = ftell(f) / 16;
fclose(f);

FILE *fileRB = fopen("data_output.bin", "rb");
int **data_read = (int **)malloc(length * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    data_read[i] = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));


for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    fread(data_read[i], sizeof(data_read[i][length]), sizeof(data_read), fileRB);

fclose(fileRB);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", data_read[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am newbie in C. It would be cool, if someone can help me with it.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fread(data_read[i], sizeof(int), length, fileRB)`?

Comment: `sizeof(data_read)` is size of a pointer